# Can't add Facebook SDK Xcode 8 with GoogleMaps SDK (incompatible)

Tags: ios, facebook, google-maps, cocoapods, xcode8

I'm trying to add FacebookSDK on my app but I can't, it's getting some errors.
I already install GoogleMaps using Cocoapods.

So first I tried to use Cocoapods in order to install Facebook but it can't. Showing this error in the Terminal

```
[!] The 'Pods-test' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries:
```

(/Users/devews/Desktop/test/Pods/GoogleMaps/Base/Frameworks/GoogleMapsBase.framework, /Users/devews/Desktop/test/Pods/GoogleMaps/Maps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework, and /Users/devews/Desktop/test/Pods/GoogleMaps/Maps/Frameworks/GoogleMapsCore.framework)

Here's my podfile :

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
target 'test' do

# Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to 
use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!

pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'
pod 'Bolts'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'

end
```

Second, I tried to add Facebook using Cocoapods too and by deleting the "use_frameworks!" line who cause the last issue, the pod install Facebook SDK but when I want to import the following line in the AppDelegate :

```
import FBSDKCoreKit
```

It shows "No such module 'FBSDKCoreKit'", so the Facebook SDK wasn't really installed but I can see it on the project as the following photo.

[image: error no such module]

It seems because of I deleted the line "use_frameworks!" on the podfile so it can't work.

So third, I deleted GoogleMaps in the podfile and try to add it manually, but it shows a lot of errors maybe because missing files but I don't know because I followed the GoogleMaps documentation :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start?hl=fr

So finally, I decided to reinstall GoogleMaps in the podfile and deleted the Facebook SDK from the podfile then add the Facebook SDK manually as show in the Facebook documentation, It tried to add ~/Documents/FacebookSDK in the "Framework Search Paths" but it seems is didn't change anything and nothing want to work. I think I don't need to import FBSDKCoreKit this time but when I add the following line in the AppDelegate :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyCnSxY__6RFFzp2pJbQoLj8vAQrkWb2byA")
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
return true
}
```

Then two errors very strange appears :

[image: error FB SDK]

If I click on these two errors nothing happen.
So I make a new Objective-C file call "test-Bridging-Header and write these following :

```
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.

#import <Google-Maps-iOS-Utils/GMUMarkerClustering.h>
#import "GMSMapView+ClusterKit.h"
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
```

But same issue, nothing can't work for me.

If there's someone knows how to fix that big problem because I want to use FacebookSDK and GoogleMaps SDK both inside my app and it seems impossible. I search a lot of thing on Internet but nothing can't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Maps are in static and Facebook are in dynamic so it's normal that you can't install it both with Cocoapods.
If you install GoogleMaps with Cocoapods and add FacebookSDK manually, it's the better way.
In order to resolve your last issues :

You need first to click in the Project Navigator on your project name, it seems to be for you "test" with the blue icon on the left top on corner of Xcode then go in section "Build settings", here in the search field you search for "Framework Search Paths" then here you double click on it and add the right path of the Facebook SDK in your Mac (on the Facebook for developers website they ask us to put the FacebookSDK in our Documents folder) so you just write this following path :

```
/Users/$(USER)/Documents/FacebookSDK
```

Second thing, just on the right of "Build Settings" you can see "Build Phases", you click on it, then click on "Link Binary With Libraries" here you just need to add the same frameworks you already added by drag and drop on your project. So click on the + button and add Bolts.framework, FBSDKCoreKit.framework, FBSDKLoginKit.framework and FBSDKShareKit.framework.

Third thing, you can keep the Bridging-Header.h file you created and import :

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
```

And it's alright.
Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you this is the right answer I need, you resolved my issue